# no logro conectar con mi base de datos de xampp con un dispositivo externo

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, servidor

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que conecta con una base de datos alojada en mi propio pc, via Xampp. En mi domicilio no dispongo de conexión ADSL y uso la conexión compartida del móvil. En Xampp uso el puerto 8080 y el 4433 como alternativo.
Cuado intento introducir datos a la base de datos des del propio móvil que uso deconexion wifi, con la IP local no tengo problemas y la inserción es correcta, por lo que creo que los documentos php y mysql son correctos.
Cuando hago lo mismo pero con un móvil distinto, con otra conexión,claro, no logro insertar los datos con éxito, mi conexión es rechazada por el sitio web.
Introduzco la siguiente direccion en mi explorador:
http://31.221.200.84:8080/.....
Esta IP es la que obtuve desde cualesmiip.com.
Probé de deshabilitar el antivirus y tampoco.
Muchas gracias por vuestro interés, espero vuestras respuestas!!

Comment: dado que el servidor va a ser tu pc de casa, si quieres entrar a él tu router **debe tener abiertos los puertos** (en tu caso, el 8080 y el 4433) y que redirigan el trafico a la ip de tu red interna de tu pc (suele ser una tipo **192.168.1.x**, o algo parecido). No se que router tienes, busca en el manual alguna opcion tipo NAT, o Port Redirect, o algo asi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola veo algo difícil lo que quieres hacer de la forma que lo quieres hacer, pues aquí el dispositivo que es visible desde internet es el Celular con el cual compartes el servicio de internet a tu computadora. los celulares no son tan administrables como un router, pues lo que tendrías que configurar es que el trafico que llegue desde internet direccionarlo a la computadora, en un router es fácil pues nada mas revisas que ip local tienes en tu computadora y configuras el seguimiento en el router o habilitas en algunos router el modo DMZ (algo asi) a la ip local de tu computadora para que todo el trafico se redireccione a esa ip local. estas funciones no las tienen los celulares por lo regular.

lo que yo te recomendaría es que te abrieras una cuanta de hosting, para hacer tus pruebas. si no puedes pagar por el motivo que sea. existe hostiger te da una cuanta gratis SIN PUBLICIDAD, que esto ultimo es importante. ademas te da:
2000 MB Espacio
100 GB de Ancho de banda
Autoinstalador
Sin Anuncios
Creador de Sitios
2 Bases de Datos MySQL Gratuitas
2 cuentas de correo.
sub Dominio gratis.
Y ES GRATIS...

googlealo o sigue este link para abrir tu cuenta gratis. [Haz click aqui](http://api.hostinger.mx/redir/1885238)

saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Rauls,de hecho en paralelo también estaba intentando esta alternativa de Hostinger, precisamente, allí también me encuentro con dificultades, pero queria indicarlas en otro post... muchas gracias, de nuevo!